MAUI navigate the Flyout Items from codebehind
I want to navigate the FlyoutItems from codebehind.   The usual Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(PageTwo)); doesn't work the same way.
Demo:
I created a default MAUI app in Visual Studio 2022. I install nuget CommunityToolkit.MVVM.Input.  I added 3 XAML Contentpages.
In App.Shell.xaml I add the 3 flyout items.  When I run the app they appear and work perfectly.  Note the Menus' "selectedItem" syncs up effortlessly.  This is the behaviour I want to use from codebehind / viewmodel.
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
Title="DeleteMe2">


<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Page One"
        Icon="one_icon.png"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PageOne}"
        Route="PageOne" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="Page Two"
        Icon="two_icon.png"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PageTwo}"
        Route="PageTwo" />
    <ShellContent
        Title="Page Three"
        Icon="three_icon.png"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PageThree}"
        IsVisible="true"
        Route="PageThree" />

</FlyoutItem>

On the pages there are buttons to "do something" and then navigate to the other pages. In the ViewModel.  This appears to create a new instance of the other pages and the navigation properties are lost.
[RelayCommand]
public void GoToPageTwo()
{
    //this opens a new instance of PageTwo
    //and has a "Back" arrow on the top left
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(PageTwo));
}

[RelayCommand]
public void GoToPageThree()
{
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(PageThree));
}

So in my code behind I want to mimic the behaviour of either tapping the Flyout Menu items or the buttons on the bottom of the Pages


In your case, all of the three pages are root page. So you can call the following code to change the root page of the Navigation stack.
[RelayCommand]
public void GoToPageTwo()
{
    //this opens a new instance of PageTwo
    //and has a "Back" arrow on the top left
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//PageTwo");
}

[RelayCommand]
public void GoToPageThree()
{
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//PageThree");
}

In addition, the Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///PageThree"); is also work. For more information, you can check the official document about Relative routes.

Perfect start to my Monday morning - Thank you :)
